# Are there any c to bytecode compilers?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bytecode

How complete are they?
any benchmarks?
Were any of them ever popular?

P.S. are there any other non garbage collected languages that have and/or had bytecode compilers(ex pascal)?

Comment: I thought LLVM did something like this, but I can't find anything concrete on it.

Comment: I think thats just intermediate compiler representation although I heard some people were thinking of trying to have some non architecture specific intermediate code for Portable Native Client (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client).

Comment: Microsoft's C compiler has been able to compile to bytecode for decades. The UCSD Pascal compiler has done so for even longer!

Comment: Here's a list of em: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#C_to_bytecode_compilers

Comment: gabe and bdares thanks for the answer but could you put them down as answers(possibly including command line option for microsofts c compiler to compile to bytecode and how to run it and mentioning that that is a list of compilers to jvm bytecode?

Comment: @detly: http://llvm.org is concrete.

Comment: @Roman A. Taycher: Did you get a useful answer in only half of all question-threads you opened?

Comment: @detly LLVM's IR is its bytecode. You can cary it throughout the compilation process and even keep it until the program is about to be executed (at which point you'll need to use its [JIT](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl4.html)). There are even mentions of a GC within the LLVM documentation but I haven't played with those parts so I can't say how much of a VM it is. Oh and you'll need [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) to generate the bytecode for a C program.

Comment: @phresnel - I meant concrete info on whether the IR LLVM uses can be distributed and executed on other architectures. I didn't look too hard though.

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a historical answer, but one of the best-known Pascal Compilers - [UCSD Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCSD_Pascal) was based entirely around an interpreted/emulated "P-code" system, which is cited by [James Gosling as a major influence on Java VM and bytecode](http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/software/javas-forgotten-forbear/0):

> "Then fast-forward a bunch of years, when I was trying to do the
>   project that Java came out of," said Gosling in an interview for ACM
>   Queue. "I had to do this architecture-neutral distribution format, and
>   then I just went ka-ching! You know, this p-code translator thing
>   would actually just drop in there."

Answer (score 1):

If by bytecode, you mean any C Virtual Machine:

There's the [UEFI standard](http://www.uefi.org/home/), which offers a C virtual machine, and at least the [Intel EFI compiler](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-for-efi-byte-code-documentation/) for earlier versions of it.

Not bytecode, but [CInt](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=29670&dl=ACM&coll=DL&CFID=34575721&CFTOKEN=75901071) defines an interpreter for C code.